# angularjs material design and flex layout

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I have created three layouts with flex=44,flex=20 and flex=44.
Basically 3 columns on the page.

```
  <div flex="44">

  </div>
  <div flex="20" class="rightcol">

  </div>
  <div flex="44" class="rightcol">
    <div class="" ui-view>

    </div>
  </div>
```

I want to change the flex value or infact merge two flex and make it as one.

Is it possible to achieve from the controllers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the flex-value in the scope of the controller:

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.flex1 = function () { return 44; };
    $scope.flex2 = function () { return 20; };
    $scope.flex3 = function () { return 44; };

    $scope.showFlex = function (n) {
      // your condition whether the flex-ed div should be shown goes in here
      return true;
    }
});
```

Your HTML should look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div flex="{{flex1()}}" ng-if="showFlex(1)"> 

  </div>
  <div flex="{{flex2()}}" ng-if="showFlex(2)" class="rightcol">

  </div>
  <div flex="{{flex3()}}" ng-if="showFlex(3)" class="rightcol">
    <div class="" ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```